# How to select a classes with same name without using incremental id

Tags: php, html, jquery

[image]Is there other ways to select classes with same name but in different table rows?
I use html class="className + id" Than in jquery to select $('.className'+id)... some code
I would like to avoid using the id each time. Some suggestions?
Thank you

```
HMTL
Data retrieved from the database
<tr class="row" id="<?= $id;?>"> <!-- id 1 -->
   <td  class="atyp<?= $id;?>"> <?= $v['atyp'];?> </td>

 <tr class="row" id="<?= $id;?>"> <!-- id 2 -->
   <td  class="atyp<?= $id;?>"> <?= $v['atyp'];?> </td>

JQUERY
<script>
$('.atyp'+id).val() // some code....
</script>
```

So the table has multiple rows with same class name and I would like to avoid to use id to select a specific class

Comment: What are you actually doing with these rows? If you are trying to handle a click event for example, you don't need an ID at all. `$('.atyp').on('click', function() { var elem = $(this) }` where elem will be equal to the clicked element.

Comment: Yes i see,. i do multiple functions withs rows. I use a selector to change the status of a flight and is updating into the db (php>sql). So i need the id but i don't want to use the id in each <td class="flight<?= $id;?>">  To find the specific id I use the  <tr id="<?= $id;?>">  'ad than $(this).closest('tr').attr('id')  to get the id before using ajax. Once the sql is done i use jquery to update data in the table using class+id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put `<?= $id;?>` to your classes:

```html
<tr class="row" id="<?= $id;?>"> <!-- id 1 -->
   <td  class="atyp atyp<?= $id;?>"> <?= $v['atyp'];?> </td>

 <tr class="row" id="<?= $id;?>"> <!-- id 2 -->
   <td  class="atyp atyp<?= $id;?>"> <?= $v['atyp'];?> </td>
```

```js
$('.atyp').val()
```

Comment: yes but it will select all the tables rows with the same classname, I want to select a specific <td> class . E.G. How to select the first .atyp class and not the second ?

Comment: @Frenzye `.row:first-child .atyp`?

Comment: Also you can use `$('.row .atyp').eq(2)`

Comment: I don't know at which position the TR is positionated because in the table there are more than 50 rows. I don't think that this coulb be the solution. Thank you anyway

Comment: The code is automatically executed, I don't have to manually select the class in the TD

Comment: @Frenzye What exactly you want to do?

Comment: I ve just replied to GrumpyCrouton above, please take a look at my comment

Comment: @Frenzye So if you have `$(this)` that's already inside proper row, do `$(this).closest('tr').find('.atyp')`. Have you considered using FrontEnd framework like Angular for this job? It would be 100% better and easier to handle DOM manipulations

Comment: Ok I'm gonna try this and let you know. Thank you. I have to learn before using it

Answer (score 0):

You should not give multiple HTML elements the same ID.

You can select the first td with the [:first-of-type](https://api.jquery.com/first-of-type-selector/) selector

```
$("td:first-of-type")
```

In general you can use the [:nth-of-type](https://api.jquery.com/nth-of-type-selector/) selector.

```
$("td:nth-of-type(42)")
```

Comment: Yes but data is retrieved from database and I don't know which table row the function will be executed, I use the ID to be shure that is the good one, but I would like to avoid this. That's why my question

Comment: And is working properly in my way, but I'm just trying to not use the same id for multiple elements

Comment: What do you mean by "is the good one"?

Comment: retrieveing data from db with autoincrement it gives: id:1, id:2, id,3 and so on, and in generating table rows. I have to access a class that for all the id has the same name. so using classname+id, but I want to avoid to use id

Comment: I have added an image above maybe it could help to better understand